# How can I use a class and constructor in a another class, method and store them to my list? C#

Tags: c#, list, class, methods, constructor

How can I use a class and constructor in a another class and method?
I would like to be able to have a menu in the main method and add names to my list via the method Add_them().

**One of the errors is that the name does not exist in the current context**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace test
{
    class Poll
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Poll(string name)

        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number for the option you want");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add names");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Stop program");
            var polls = new List<string>();
            string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            int userNumber;
            int.TryParse(userChoice, out userNumber);
            if (userNumber == 1)
            {
                Add_them(polls);

            }
            else if (userNumber == 2)
            {
                End_it();
            }
        }

        static void Add_them(List<string> polls)
        {
            string u = null;
            do
            {
                Poll poll1 = new Poll(string name); // ERROR
                Console.WriteLine("Name:");
                poll1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Write end to stop or enter and continue on");
                u = Console.ReadLine();
                polls.Add();
            } while (u != "end");
        }
        static void End_it()
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Poll poll1 = new Poll(Console.ReadLine());` would work.

Comment: You have to read user input first, then pass it to the Poll constructor

Comment: There were quite a few problems. This compiles: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y6iwFT - but I don't guarantee it is logically correct

Answer (score 0):

This line: `Poll poll1 = new Poll(string name);` needs to be changed to actually use a string, a string is anything inside double quotes `""` so for example:

`Poll poll1 = new Poll("Poll1");`

if you want to set it to an empty value then the string class has a static member called `Empty`:

`Poll poll1 = new Poll(string.Empty);`

Comment: Better to read the line into a local string variable and then construct the object - i.e. "prefer immutable objects".